# Как установить плагин VirtualKeyboard для Qt 5.15.1

Tags: qt, qml

Мне в проекте для Андроида нужно изменять положение виджетов на экране при открытии клавиатуры, по идее для этого можно использовать классы плагина virtual keyboard, однако, он у меня установлен был для всех компиляторов, только не для андроид. Я решил попробовать переустановить его через MaintenanceTool, удалил его и заново поставив, однако, после удаления, он стал недоступен в тулзе.
Плагин есть на гите Qt, есть способ доустановить его из исходников? Если да, то как?

Comment: Вроде, этого плагина никогда небыло для андроида. `The Qt Virtual Keyboard project provides an input framework and reference keyboard frontend for Qt 5 on Linux Desktop/X11, Windows Desktop, and Boot2Qt targets.` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html

Comment: @Chorkov 
Есть довольно много старых тем на стэке на счёт функций этого плагина на андроиде. Здесь, например, в одном из комментов пишут, что в 5.6 заработало на Андроиде https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028153/qml-virtual-keyboard-dimensions.

Comment: там обсуждается QInputMethod;;keyboardRectangle, который является частью GUI, но не частью плагина  VirtualKeyboard. У анероида есть  своя клавиатура, и  плагин для  рисования клавиатуры средствами qt - ненужен.